# Linking to a file on server in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, server

I hava a website in Wordpress. Let's say is installed on a domain www.something.com.

I know how to get to individual files, but is it possible to make a link to a file, so that the URL would be: www.something.com/pdf/article1.pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Yes ofcus, Simply put in the link like so, in your html/text 
`Download <a href=http://www.something.com/pdf/article1.pdf">here</a>` 
 to refer to the file, and make sure u have the pdf folder created in your root directory.
Good luck.

Comment: But that did't work for me. Well i did not test it with a link on the site but via direct URL in browser. How should i put the files on the server? Currently i put them via ftp on: public_html/pdf/x.pdf? Should it be somewhere else?